# nativescript cli sidekick with nvm

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-sidekick

When I use nvm to install a recent version of node, I have to reinstall tns. I can do that with the command npm i -g nativescript@latest. If I check tns --version I get the appropriate version. However, Nativescript Sidekick keeps telling me to run that command and will not launch. Has anyone gotten Nativescript with node to work with nvm?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. I had to set the default node version to a lower than current version to work with Nativescript Sidekick.

```
nvm alias default 10.13.0
```